# jquery isotope - centered & corner-stamp

Tags: jquery, jquery-isotope

i'm using isotope plugin with centered layout. There is no problem. Container width increase or decrease by active column count. But it's dont resize container width when i add a corner stamp to layout. How can i solve?

[centered & without corner-stamp](http://jsfiddle.net/salt/QNkVF/)

[centered & corner-stamp](http://jsfiddle.net/salt/Cc2JC/)

Comment: Maybe [this clever code, see fiddles][1] can be leveraged in your case.


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/a/11905171/963514