# Isotope grid + corner stamp removing empty spaces, sorting logic

Tags: jquery, jquery-isotope

This question is related to this older one: [Isotope Grid layout use empty space](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11612399/isotope-grid-layout-use-empty-space)

Here is the fiddle I am working with: 
http://jsfiddle.net/zewkG/4/

The issue is that when the sorting logic that works in that previous question's answer fails as soon as the masonry cornerstamp [as coded by the creator of isotope] is added. I have been trying to figure out the logic behind this one, but unfortunately to no avail and with a lot of time wasted without a breakthrough. [There should not be any missing boxes when you click on the fifth element, as well as it shouldn't go two lines down, just one. The first three elements should take the first line instead of going down one line.]

The above fiddle contains the sorting logic of the previous question with only the fourth column and a cornerstamp added.

Would love any help I can get!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

See http://jsfiddle.net/zewkG/6/, I hope I understood well what you want

**Edit**:

If you want 21 boxes, see http://jsfiddle.net/zewkG/8/

**Edit 2**:

http://jsfiddle.net/zewkG/8/ has a bug: boxes number 13,17,21 (at the end of the row), when clicked, they go to the following row instead to the beginning of its row. Fixed in http://jsfiddle.net/zewkG/9/

Comment: Thanks so much! There is only one issue: http://jsfiddle.net/zewkG/7/ click on 17 or 16. Everything works fine except those two right now. Any ideas?

Comment: I have a follow up question due to a problem that I ran into. I understand why it is happening but not sure how to adjust your code to make it work. 

If I use a filter and some elements are hidden. The layout with gaps comes back.

Comment: Sorry had to make a fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/zewkG/13/ If you click on the cornerstamp to do a sort. And then follow up by click on I 11 and 15. Gaps come back. I know that this is because the index is really not /changed/ I am wondering how this can be adjusted to fit this.

Comment: I have created a new question for this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11977800/isotope-custom-filtering-based-on-the-index-not-working-after-a-filter for ease of reading.