# Isotope custom sorting based on the index not working after a filter

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-isotope

This question is a follow-up to this one:  [Isotope grid + corner stamp removing empty spaces, sorting logic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11904302/isotope-grid-corner-stamp-removing-empty-spaces-sorting-logic)

The answer there works flawlessly on the unfiltered isotope layout. Once some elements are removed though, this functionality stops working.

I am wondering if there is a good way to modify the code in the previous answer in order to accommodate for this.

**Here is a fiddle with a basic filter added on click of the corner-stamp: http://jsfiddle.net/zewkG/13/**

Note when, after clicking the corner-stamp to filter, you click on element 11 or 15 the layout has gaps once again.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

here you have the solution: http://jsfiddle.net/zewkG/14/

```
$('.corner-stamp').click( function() {
    $container.isotope( 'destroy' );
    grid('.item.odd');
    $container.isotope('remove', $('.item:not(.odd)') )    
    $container.isotope('updateSortData', $('.item.odd'));
});
```

**Edit:**

Fixed answer: http://jsfiddle.net/zewkG/16/

The problem was here:

```
getSortData : {
      fitOrder : function( $item ) {
        var index = $item.index();
```

It should be:

```
getSortData : {
      fitOrder : function( $item ) {
        var index = $item.index(selector);
```

And this way we can remove the ugly `-1` we had in the sorting logic:

```
if ( $item.hasClass('large')) {
      if(index>10){
          order = Math.floor((index-1) / (columns))*(columns) + 1.5;
      }else{
          order = Math.floor((index-1) / (columns-1))*(columns-1) + .5;
      }
}
```

becomes

```
if ( $item.hasClass('large')) {
      if(index>10){
          order = Math.floor((index) / (columns))*(columns) + 1.5;
      }else{
          order = Math.floor((index) / (columns-1))*(columns-1) + .5;
      }
}
```

That's because

- When we have all boxes, box1's index is 0, box2's index is 1, box3's index is 2...
- When we have the odd ones, box1's index is 0, box3's index is 1,
  box5's index is 2...

So we break the correspondence between a box's text and its index in order to mantain the sorting logic.

Finally,

```
$('.corner-stamp').click( function() {
    $container.isotope( 'destroy' );
    grid('.item.odd');
    $('.item:not(.odd)').css('display','none');   
});
```

We need `$('.item:not(.odd)').css('display','none')` because if we don't do that the even boxes are shown under the animated odd boxes.

**Edit 2:**

Do you remember that I found that http://jsfiddle.net/zewkG/8/ had a bug: boxes number 13,17,21 (at the end of the row), when clicked, they went to the following row instead to the beginning of its row; so I fixed it in http://jsfiddle.net/zewkG/9/?

But after that it seems we had a regresion and the fixed sorting logic was replaced by the old one.

So I fixed your http://jsfiddle.net/zewkG/19/ in http://jsfiddle.net/zewkG/20/

The fixed sorting logic is:

```
if ($item.hasClass('large')) {
    if(index>10){
        order = Math.floor((index-1) / (columns))*(columns) + 1.5;
    }else{
        order = Math.floor((index) / (columns-1))*(columns-1) + .5;
    }
}else {
    order = index + 1;
}
```

Comment: I was afraid it would have to be this way, is there a way to destroy with an animation?

Comment: @BorisKourt What do you mean with "with an animation"? Anyway, I don't think I can help you more, because I'm not used to jQuery, even less to Isotope. I could find out the code of the answer above using intuition, looking at Isotope's web page and some tests. But I can't help you with the depths of that library...

Comment: Eh its alright, this will work for now so I will mark it as answered. By animation I meant that isotope destroy just instantly transitions into a new set of elements. Normally when you filter it fades out the unused ones with an animation. 

Thanks again for your help. :)

Comment: I will have to mark this one as un-answered again, as remove removes the elements from the dom as well preventing them from being re-added to isotope if another sort has to be applied.

Comment: @BorisKourt I have found where the problem was, fixed here: http://jsfiddle.net/zewkG/16/

Comment: Brilliant! I have been trying to figure it out by myself but was looking within the  new code rather than back in the order. I have combined your code with some minor tweaks I did so that it works with multiple sorts and a reset: http://jsfiddle.net/zewkG/19/ Thanks again for your help! :)

Comment: @BorisKourt Don't mention it. But I found that we had a regresion bug, I fixed your http://jsfiddle.net/zewkG/19/ in http://jsfiddle.net/zewkG/20/